# Swift Custom Navigation Controller Class

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift3, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Everyone who reads it, hello and thank you. I am writing an application like Viber or WhatsApp for iOS devices using Xcode 8.2.1 and Swift 3.0. I have a problem: I want my app has a navigation controller but not a simple one, I want it to be a custom one. There is a print screen from WhatsApp to be understanding, what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Screenshot of WhatsApp chat with somebody]

As we can see, this navigation controller has 3 buttons, label and image with avatar. I also want to change my color to green one. Due to do this I have created class:

```
import UIKit

class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green


        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 39, height: 39))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let image = UIImage(named: "logo")
        imageView.image = image
        navigationItem.titleView = imageView


    }
}
```

And it gives this result:
[image]
As you can see it is without picture. I know that if I add this code:

```
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 39, height: 39))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let image = UIImage(named: "logo")
        imageView.image = image
        navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

to ViewController, image with logo will appear but I want complete class which I will connect somewhere (for example, in Interface Builder) and it will make a beautiful Navigation Controller with buttons, images and etc. Moreover, I can create a different class with another Navigation Controller and connect it to different screens, on which, for example, I will not need images, only buttons. So question is: how to make custom Navigation Controller class?

I will be really glad and thankful for any help, Thank You!

Comment: how have you achieve this?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: Hi, guys! I think, I have an answer. I will try to put it here ASAP.

Comment: @KrutikaSonawala, I have posted my answer, please, vote and comment it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Now, I know the answer! It will be written for Swift 4.1.2. Each class inherited from `UIViewController` has a property `self.navigationController?.navigationBar` or `navigationItem`. You can create you own class like this:

```
class CustomNavigationController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let color = UIColor(red: 81 / 255, green: 155 / 255, blue: 22 / 255, alpha: 1.0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = color

        let image = UIImage(named: "logo")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    }

    private func imageView(imageName: String) -> UIImageView {
        let logo = UIImage(named: imageName)
        let logoImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35))
        logoImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        logoImageView.image = logo
        logoImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
        logoImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
        return logoImageView
    }

    func barImageView(imageName: String) -> UIBarButtonItem {
        return UIBarButtonItem(customView: imageView(imageName: imageName))
    }

    func barButton(imageName: String, selector: Selector) -> UIBarButtonItem {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: imageName), for: .normal)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35)
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
        button.addTarget(self, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)
        return UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    }

}
```

Now you can inherit any of you UIViewControllers from this class `CustomNavigationController` and add ass much buttons, icons, change colors, logos and etc. as much as you want (of course, in normal range)! Like this:

```
class ViewController: CustomNavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barImageView(imageName: "picture1")

        let firstImage = barImageView(imageName: "picture2")
        let secondButton = barButton(imageName: "picture3", selector: #selector(secondButtonPressed))

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [firstImage, secondButton]
    }

    @objc func secondButtonPressed() {
        print("Pressed")
    }

}
```

This is my solution, maybe not the best, but 100% works! Thank you!

Comment: Just a remark here. I have came to the same conclusion that this will be the best solution for such cases like this. But I would suggest another even better one. Extend the UIViewController itself with these methods. That is better and cleaner.